# Webpack 2.0 checking existence of tree shaken ES6 module imports

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-module-loader

In Webpack 2.0 (@2.1.0-beta6), if I go to import a file that points to a file that doesn't exist, I get a build time error.

```
//x.js
import { foo } from './y'

//y.js
export function foo () { return 5 }
```

If I go to import an export that doesn't exist from a file that exists, I get a runtime error.

```
//x.js
import { baz } from './y'

//y.js
export function foo () { return 5 }
```

Is there a way to have Webpack check exports in the same way it resolves files?

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015-native-modules']
        }
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: It's worth pasting your `webpack config` file content here.

Comment: try  `export default module.exports = { /* code */ };`

Comment: @Venky isn't that just the same as `module.exports = { /* code */ }`? You lose the ability to tree shake with CommonJS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `webpack@2.1-beta15`, [warnings have now been added](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2713) for imports of ES6 exports.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a runtime error in this case is correct behavior. You probably aren't getting a runtime error from the import itself, but only when you try and use it it is undefined.

A file existing or not can be easily determined by a system call during build time. However, a module exporting a given value or not can be changed at runtime - not that that is a good idea - so Webpack doesn't make a build time decision as to whether or not it should bail out.

Consider the following code:

```
// hats.js
var hats = undefined;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  hats = 'i have a hat!';
}
export const HATS = hats;
// index.js
import { HATS } from './hats';
console.log('hats is:', HATS}
```

Webpack can't know at build time whether or not HATS is going to exist at run time, so it won't error out when I try and import hats. However, HATS will correctly be either undefined or 'i have a hat!' when logged during execution. Similarly, if i remove the export line from hats.js, it will simply always report undefined, because Webpack cannot tell the difference after transpilation - HATS is simply undefined still. If I remove hats.js completely, Webpack knows something is definitely wrong and errors out.

Comment: With webpack@2 at least, there is no transpilation involved in module resolution.